# In IIS can I change the default document per folder via web.config?

Tags: web-config, windows-server, default-document

I have a certain PHP file on my windows server in a directory that requires you to add index.php in order to view it.

The below works:
http://example.org/placestorun/index

But the following does not work:
http://example.org/placestorun/

I added a web.config file to the places to run directory to make it work without the index.php using the below code in the folder's web.config file:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.php" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The above is not working though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just doing a rewrite in web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule placestoswim" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This was also my last resort. Everything else failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add clear to remove all the inherited elements:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.php" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also make sure your app is not running in classic mode but in integrated mode.

Comment: That didn't work. Adding that clear tag does not work. Do I need to add a remove tag to stop it from being default.aspx etc..?

Comment: clear should be sufficient. Check your application pool, is it running in classic mode or integrated mode?

Comment: It's running intergrated

Comment: What do you see when it's not working? Another default page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168355/discussion-between-peter-bartels-and-sjw0525).